# mysite.com/new redirects to mysite.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I just rebuilt my site to be responsive with Gantry 5 and Joomla.  built in inmotion hosting server. moved it into a sub domain on my real sites server, www.umiultrasound.com/new.  when i try to access the site to test it redirects to www.umiultrasound.com.

I have discussed this with my host, they say i have a wildcard redirect- i don't.  they say to check my .htaccess file.  i did but i do not see where i am redirecting / or www.mysite.com to itself.

they then recommended that i read one of your forum results.  the one they sent didn't apply to me.  hoping you can help

Comment: Sounds like you need to drop your host ;) Could the redirect be happening at the DNS level? Check there first and then check all directories from the root down to the index file to make sure there aren't any nested .htaccess files interfering. Also, if you could post the contents of the .htaccess file we can look for any red flags. Sounds silly but have you tried on other machines/networks? I've has to flush DNS cache in Chrome before for stubborn redirect issues.

Comment: .htaccess info is quite long  not enough space here.  is there an upload method i could use?

Answer (score 0):

Check for any `RewriteBase` command in `.htaccess`. You could also temporarily copy the standard `htaccess.txt` over `.htaccess` to see if this makes any difference (backup `.htaccess` to `.htaccess.old` or similar first).

Also check your `configuration.php` file to see if the `live_site` parameter has been set.